Position sticky in grid container works not as expected
When scrolling  the page I need the imageContainer to be sticky untill the end of itemFeatures box scroll down to the end of this box.
Both of these containers are in thumb. Thumb is display: grid.
When I copy this code to sandbox it works as expected. I tried to use overflow-y: auto then vertical scrollbar appears in itemFeatures container. But I don't need it.


.thumb {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;

  .imageContainer {
    height: 442px;
    width: 340px;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      height: 925px;
      width: 712px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1360px) {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      height: 800px;
      width: 650px;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

    .mySwiper3 {
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .mySwiper4 {
      height: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .mySwiper4 .swiper-slide {
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }

    .mySwiper4 .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }

  .itemImg {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    * {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  
  .itemDescription {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 40px;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
  }

  .itemDescriptionText {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
    text-align: justify;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 30px 0 60px 0;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1360px) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 60px;
    height: 1200px;

    .itemImg {
      img {
        width: 650px;
      }
    }
  }
}
    <div class="cardContainer">
        <nav aria-label="breadCrumb">
            <ul class="breadCrumb">
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><a href="index.html" title="На головну сторінку"><svg width="12px"
                            height="12px" class="homeIcon">
                            <use href="~images/svg/house.svg#house"></use>
                        </svg></a></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><span>&#62;</span></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><a href="categories.html " title="Перехід в Категорії">Категорії</a></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><span>&#62;</span></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem active" aria-current="page">Назва поточного товару(Cheyenne Copy)</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="imageContainer">
                <div class="swiper mySwiper3">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #1"
                                    src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #2"
                                    src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #3"
                                    src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #4"
                                    src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #5"
                                    src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                </div>
                <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper4">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)"
                                    type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="itemFeatures">
                <div class="itemWrapper">
                    <p class="itemTitle">Cheyenne Copy</p>
                    <p class="price">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle">Вибрати опцію </span>
                        <svg class="arrow">
                            <use href="~images/svg/arrowCard.svg#arrow"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="dropdown-item">Опція 1</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-item">Опція 2</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-item">Опція 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quantityItem">
                        <div class="descending">-</div>
                        <span class="number">1</span>
                        <div class="ascending">+</div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="itemButton" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>
                <p class="itemDescription">Опис</p>
                <p class="itemDescriptionText">Текст машинки Текст про Текст машинки. про тату тату машинки про тату про
                    про машинки тату тату Текст тату тату. про про Текст машинки тату тату про тату. тату Текст
                    татуТекст машинки Текст. машинки машинки про про тату Текст Текст машинки. про Текст Текст Текст
                    Текст про про машинки Текст Текст Текст машинки машинки Текст. машинки тату про Текст Текст Текст
                    тату тату Текст машинки.
                </p>
                <h2 class="featuresTitle">Характеристики</h2>
                <div class="tableContainer">
                    <p class="featureItem">Країна виробника</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Інший</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Обертів</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">8000 об/хв на 8В</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Хід</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">3,5 мм</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Виліт голки</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">0–4,5 мм</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">У комплекті</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">шнур, картридж, перехідник, машинка</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Двигун</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">4.5 Вт (Тайвань)</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Рівень шуму</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Низький рівень шуму</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Нагрів</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Не нагрівається під час тривалих сеансів </p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Робоча напруга</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">7–12 В</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Живлення</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Сумісна з усіма блоками живлення</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Потужність</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Потужна</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h2 class="similarItems"> З цим товаром беруть</h2>
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>

                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>

                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>

                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"
                            type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-container" id="brands">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/01.webp" alt="Image 1"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/02.webp" alt="Image 2"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/03.webp" alt="Image 3"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/04.webp" alt="Image 4"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/05.webp" alt="Image 5"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/06.webp" alt="Image 6"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/07.webp" alt="Image 7"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/08.webp" alt="Image 8"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/09.webp" alt="Image 9"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/10.webp" alt="Image 10"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/11.webp" alt="Image 11"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/12.webp" alt="Image 12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>




Your CSS code does not seem to activate in the Snippet. Please [edit] to fix.

In your case just remove the .thumb height: 1200px; because your itemFeatures div height is approx 1400px up. So when the imageContainer height is over the sticky container is removed. If you set imageContainer sticky when scrolling till the end then remove your parent div height.


.thumb {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;

  .imageContainer {
    height: 442px;
    width: 340px;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      height: 925px;
      width: 712px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1360px) {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      height: 800px;
      width: 650px;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

    .mySwiper3 {
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .mySwiper4 {
      height: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .mySwiper4 .swiper-slide {
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }

    .mySwiper4 .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }

  .itemImg {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    * {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  
  .itemDescription {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 40px;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
  }

  .itemDescriptionText {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
    text-align: justify;

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 30px 0 60px 0;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1360px) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 60px;

    .itemImg {
      img {
        width: 650px;
      }
    }
  }
}
<div class="cardContainer">
        <nav aria-label="breadCrumb">
            <ul class="breadCrumb">
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><a href="index.html" title="На головну сторінку"><svg width="12px" height="12px" class="homeIcon">
                            <use href="~images/svg/house.svg#house"></use>
                        </svg></a></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><span>&#62;</span></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><a href="categories.html " title="Перехід в Категорії">Категорії</a></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem"><span>&#62;</span></li>
                <li class="breadCrumbItem active" aria-current="page">Назва поточного товару(Cheyenne Copy)</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="imageContainer">
                <div class="swiper mySwiper3">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #1" src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #2" src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #3" src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #4" src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="Image #5" src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                </div>
                <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper4">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <picture class="itemImg">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgDesktop.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                                <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                                <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="itemFeatures">
                <div class="itemWrapper">
                    <p class="itemTitle">Cheyenne Copy</p>
                    <p class="price">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle">Вибрати опцію </span>
                        <svg class="arrow">
                            <use href="~images/svg/arrowCard.svg#arrow"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="dropdown-item">Опція 1</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-item">Опція 2</div>
                            <div class="dropdown-item">Опція 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quantityItem">
                        <div class="descending">-</div>
                        <span class="number">1</span>
                        <div class="ascending">+</div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="itemButton" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>
                <p class="itemDescription">Опис</p>
                <p class="itemDescriptionText">Текст машинки Текст про Текст машинки. про тату тату машинки про тату про
                    про машинки тату тату Текст тату тату. про про Текст машинки тату тату про тату. тату Текст
                    татуТекст машинки Текст. машинки машинки про про тату Текст Текст машинки. про Текст Текст Текст
                    Текст про про машинки Текст Текст Текст машинки машинки Текст. машинки тату про Текст Текст Текст
                    тату тату Текст машинки.
                </p>
                <h2 class="featuresTitle">Характеристики</h2>
                <div class="tableContainer">
                    <p class="featureItem">Країна виробника</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Інший</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Обертів</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">8000 об/хв на 8В</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Хід</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">3,5 мм</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Виліт голки</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">0–4,5 мм</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">У комплекті</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">шнур, картридж, перехідник, машинка</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Двигун</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">4.5 Вт (Тайвань)</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Рівень шуму</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Низький рівень шуму</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Нагрів</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Не нагрівається під час тривалих сеансів </p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Робоча напруга</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">7–12 В</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Живлення</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Сумісна з усіма блоками живлення</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Потужність</p>
                    <p class="featureItem">Потужна</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="similarItems"> З цим товаром беруть</h2>
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide similarItemCard">
                    <picture class="itemImgSim">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimDesk.webp" media="(min-width: 1360px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgSimTab.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
                        <source srcset="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" media="(min-width: 390px)" type="image/webp">
                        <img src="~images/img/card/itemImgMob.webp" alt="Cheyenne Copy">
                    </picture>
                    <h3 class="itemTitleSim">Cheyenne Copy</h3>
                    <p class="itemPriceSim">2 055 ₴</p>
                    <button class="itemButton sim" type="submit">Додати до кошика</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-container" id="brands">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/01.webp" alt="Image 1"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/02.webp" alt="Image 2"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/03.webp" alt="Image 3"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/04.webp" alt="Image 4"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/05.webp" alt="Image 5"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/06.webp" alt="Image 6"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/07.webp" alt="Image 7"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/08.webp" alt="Image 8"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/09.webp" alt="Image 9"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/10.webp" alt="Image 10"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/11.webp" alt="Image 11"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="sliderImg" src="~images/img/slider/12.webp" alt="Image 12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



When the parent div thumb height is over the sticky section is automatically removed and other div like mySwiper content is shown as well.

I have removed that height property at the .thumb, but it still doesn't take effect Here
https://codepen.io/vtabashnyuk/pen/ExBBLYx I just copy/paste my code and styles, and sticky effect work properly, but in my project it doesn't.

@VolodymyrTabashnyuk In your above link effect is working properly. I think changing the editor view middle one to show output below the code and scroll down to the bottom imageContainer is sticky till the parent div.
